# Get CSRF token in Jmeter for salesforce load-testing

Tags: performance, jmeter, salesforce, csrf, load-testing

I am trying to do the load testing of salesforce.com. I am logging via test.salesforce.com which is redirecting me to the console url. Now, subsequent post request accepts following post parameters.

- ViewStateCSRF
- ViewStateMAC
- visualforce.ViewState

But this post request is failing with "invalid session" error message.
I am guessing this is because of CSRF token. I am trying to extract(post processor in Jmeter) CSRF token, but I am unable to find this token anywhere in the response/cookie of previous requests. In one of the HTML response, I can find few CSRF tokens(e.g: runApexCsrfToken, consoleAjaxCsrfToken etc). I have tried all of them but no result.

**To summarize my problem**: I need to pass csrf token in post login request but I am unable to find this token in previous responses.

Could you please help me with this.

PS: I have tried get request on "https://c.salesforce.com/libs/granite/csrf/token.json" after login but did not find any token in response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Make sure to check all response fields as the token can be a part of URL or come as a [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
3. You need to correlate not only `ViewStateCSRF` but all other dynamic parameters as well

If you have problems with identifying the source for the dynamic parameters values you can try recording your scenario using cloud-based proxy service, it is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I was hoping to get a response from you. Thanks a lot for your help. One quick question, from where I can use smart JMX. I am unable to find it chrome extension.

Comment: @shantanu..It is cloud based service provided by Blazemeter. Check the link "How to cut your jmeter scripting time by 80%" for more details provided by Dmitri T.

Comment: In order to get the answer you need to provide more input, i.e. dump of requests sent by JMeter captured by a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or share your credentials and scenario you're trying to simulate. Given limited input from your side I can come up only with a generic piece of advice.

Comment: Thank Guys for your prompt response. I am  following the steps mentioned here for MAC. I AM able to set the proxy server and installed the certificate. Now I am hitting the record button in chrome tab and opening the desired website(https://) in separate tab. But it doesn't record anything. Instead I am seeing some garbage recorded URL(mainly HTTP pings).  Please see the attached image here: https://ibb.co/dJJT4e
https://ibb.co/nuWgPe
https://ibb.co/cnMbqK

Comment: Just now verified. This cloud based tool is recording only HTTP based website only(not HTTPS). Not sure if I am missing some setting to enable HTTPS recording as well.

Comment: Have you visited this `http://mitm.it` URL prior to starting recording?